# Ruby on Rails: How to deploy an app on remote linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, web-deployment

I have a working ruby on rails app in my local machine running on localhost(REST APi's). I want to deploy it on remote linux server.

I searched it over google, All I got was installing ruby, rails, nginux and others. It's really confusing. To make my app to work in rails environment in linux, is it really necessary to install the entire ruby and rails. Or, is there any binary executable available where we can use it without installing.

What is minimum required software to install or configuration needed to be set to make my app work in production environment?

(For Example, when I deploy nodejs app, All I need is to put the linux nodejs binaries in server without the need for installing the entire nodejs software)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of setting up your production server will be pretty much the same as with setting up your development machine in terms of installing Ruby and its dependencies. There are no binaries that you can just copy over. In addition to that you'll have to install and set up a web server like Apache or nginx.

I recommend [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) by Digital Ocean. It goes through everything from installing ruby, to setting up the database, to configuring the web server.

They have a couple more ([here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)), which seem to be very similar, using different application and web servers, but I haven't read them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1) Ensure that you have an installation of the Ruby language, either via your Linux package manager or with rvm or the like. I recommend it be a recent version (2.2+).

2) Copy over your Rails source tree.

3) `gem install bundle`

4) `bundle install` (in the project root directory)